# How to create collection with documents dynamically in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have data of array of objects i.e,

```
$arrayObj=[{name:'Jack'},{name:'Ram'},{name:'Sham'}];
```

Now, i need to create collection dynamically with 'mycollection' collection name. After that collection should like be:-

> mycollection=>    {name:Jack},    {name:Ram},    {name:Sham}

I know how to insert data by using `Model`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution:

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({}, { strict: false, collection: 'mycollection' });

 //strict, if true then values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.
//collection, for prevent from auto append 's'.

var Thing = mongoose.model('mycollection', thingSchema);
var thing = new Thing($arrayObj);
thing.save();
```

Comment: What if I want to pass my schema model on the place of array `$arrayObj` ? How can I do that?